# Match text including a line break with re

Tags: python, regex, python-re

I have a Python code that parses a text file and finds instances of the words within a tag `@(my word)`. To do this I use, e.g.,:

```py
import re

DEF_RE = r"(@\()(?P<text>.+?)\)"

sometext = "find the @(tagged text)."

m = re.search(DEF_RE, sometext)

print(m.group("text"))
tagged text
```

However, if the file contains the tagged text split over two lines the above method doesn't work, e.g.,

```py
sometext = "find the @(tagged\ntext)."

m = re.search(DEF_RE, sometext)

print(m)
None
```

Is there are way to change my regular expression string to allow the text to be split over a line?

Comment: Turn on the DOTALL flag.`re.DOTALL`. Or replace the `.+?` with `(?:.|[\n\r])+?`

Comment: What about Replacing all newlines before searching?

Comment: Try `r"@\(.*[\n ]*.*\)"`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You should turn on the `DOTALL` flag when `search`ing.

You can either replace `re.search(DEF_RE, sometext)` with `re.search(DEF_RE, sometext, flags=re.DOTALL)`

[Proof](https://regex101.com/r/x7BuR4/1)

Comment: Never suggest `(?:.|[\n\r])+?`. There are well-known `re.S` / `re.DOTALL` / `(?s)` solutions and no need repeating that again and again.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew ok